# No such file or directory in find running .sh

Tags: python, macos, shell, makefile, terminal

Running this on osx...

```
    cd ${BUILD_DIR}/mydir && for DIR in $(find ./  '.*[^_].py' |  sed  's/\/\//\//g' | awk -F "/" '{print $2}' | sort |uniq | grep -v .py); do
            if [ -f $i/requirements.txt ]; then
               pip install -r $i/requirements.txt -t $i/
            fi

            cd ${DIR} && zip -r ${DIR}.zip *  > /dev/null && mv ${DIR}.zip ../../ && cd ../
        done

    cd ../
```

error:

(env) ➜ sh package_lambdas.sh find: .*[^_].py: No such file or directory

why?

Comment: Why is there a makefile tag on this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**find** takes as an argument a list of directories to search.  You provided what appears to be regular expression.  Because there is no directory named (literally) `.*[^_].py`, find returns an error.

Below I have revised your script to correct that mistake (if I understand your intention).  Because I see so many ill-written shell scripts these days, I've taken the liberty of "traditionalizing" it.  Please see if you don't also find it more readable.

Changes:

- use `#!/bin/sh`, guaranteed to be on an Unix-like system.  Faster than bash, unless (like OS X) it is bash.
- use lower case for variable names to distinguish from system variables (and not hide them).
- eschew braces for variables (`${var}`); they're not needed in the simple case
- do not pipe output to `/usr/bin/true`; route it to `dev/null` if that's what you mean
- **rm -f** by definition cannot fail; if you meant `|| true`, it's superfluous
- put `then` and `do` on separate lines, easier to read, and that's how the Bourne shell language was meant to be used
- Let `&&` and `||` serve as line-continuation, so you can see what's happening step by step

Other changes I would suggest:

- Use a subshell when changing the working directory temporarily.  When it terminates, the working directory is restored automatically (retained by the parent), saving you the `cd ..` step, and errors.
- Use `set -e` to cause the script to terminate on error.   For expected errors, use `|| true` explicitly.
- Change `grep .py` to `grep '\.py$'`, just for good measure.
- To avoid Tilting Matchstick Syndrome, use something other than `/` as a **sed** substitute delimiter, e.g., `sed  's://:/:g'`.  But **sed** could be avoided altogether with `awk -F '/+' '{print $2}'`.

Revised version:

```bash
#! /bin/sh

src_dir=lambdas
build_dir=bin

mkdir -p $build_dir/lambdas
rm -rf $build_dir/*.zip
cp -r $src_dir/* $build_dir/lambdas

#
# The sed is a bit complicated to be osx / linux cross compatible :
#   ( .//run.sh vs ./run.sh
#
cd $build_dir/lambdas &&
    for L in $(find .  -exec grep -l '.*[^_].py' {} + |
                    sed  's/\/\//\//g' |
                    awk -F "/" '{print $2}' |
                    sort |
                    uniq |
                    grep -v .py)
    do
        if [ -f $i/requirements.txt ]
        then
            echo "Installing requirements"
            pip install -r $i/requirements.txt -t $i/
        fi
        cd $L &&
        zip -r $L.zip *  > /dev/null &&
        mv $L.zip ../../ &&
        cd ../
    done
cd ../
```

Comment: "rm -f by definition cannot fail" -- it might never fail in this use of it, but "rm -f" in general can certainly fail.  Try `rm -f /`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

The find(1) manpage says its args are `[path ...] [expression]`, where "expression" consists of "primaries" and "operands" (-flags).  `'.*[^-].py'` doesn't look like any expression, so it's being interpreted as a path, and it's reporting that there is no file named `'.*[^-].py'` in the working directory.

Perhaps you meant:

```
find ./ -regex '.*[^-].py'
```